# Array in generic Assembly

Tags: arrays, assembly

I have a doubt about how arrays do work in generic assembly.

Basically, my textbook only mentions array once and gives the following examples of array initializing cycles (V is reserved space, the comments are my own):

```
L0 LOAD R0, V ; INSTRUCTION L0, LOAD V IN REGISTER R0
LOAD R1, 0 ; LOAD 0 INTO R1
STORE (R0)+, R1 ; SAVE R0 ADDRESS INTO R1, AUTO INCREMENT
ADD R1, #1 ; ADD 1 TO THE VALUE OF R1
CMP R1, #63 ; COMPARE R1 AND 63
BL L0 ; IF RESULT IS <0, JUMP TO L0
-------------------
L0 LOAD R0, V ; INSTRUCTION L0, LOAD V IN REGISTER R0
ADD R0, #256 ; ADD 256 TO THE VALUE OF R0
LOAD R1, 64 ; LOAD 64 INTO R1
STORE -(R0), R1 ; SAVE R0 ADDRESS INTO R1
SUB R1, #1 ; SUBTRACT 1 TO R1
BGE L0 ; IF RESULT EQUAL OR GREATER THAN 0, JUMP TO L0
```

In the first example, R0 should contain the address of the data; if I understand correctly, the first time it saves the address into R1, in the second execution it saves the address of the second word etc.

R1 works as a counter of sorts, when the 63th element gets saved the cycle ends.

My question is: HOW can either examples possibly work if R0/R1 and the V address get reset at each cycle? Wouldn't it become a loop?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I'm pretty sure the L0 label is misplaced; it should be at the STORE line.

Comment: I believe your comments for the `STORE` instructions are incorrect. The value of the register given in the second operand `R1` is stored at the address given in the first operand `(R0)+`/`-(R1)`

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev Makes sense that the L0 label is misplaced...that text is really full of typos. Thanks for confirming that.

Comment: @RossRidge I checked and yes, My comment was also indeed incorrect.